# how to determine staging or production __dev__ in app

Tags: android, react-native

I have same app distribute with different config - staging or production, both is running on user physical phones.

I am wishing to use `__DEV__` to determine if the app is running in development or production.

But `__DEV__` only work on emulator or simulator, what about app staging app on user device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to access the current environment from your react-native application you are able to use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable that has `production` value after build.

Comment: When does it happen? After build with ./gradlew assembleRelease?

Comment: And how about ./gradlew assembleDebug?